# How do I generate a class which extends a class which implements a generic interface using kotlinpoet

Tags: kotlin, kotlinpoet

Given an interface like

```
interface Builder<R> {
    fun build() : R
}
```

How do I generate a class `BooBuilder` which implements this interface using kotlinpoet.

I couldn't find an example on creating a generic interface (or class) in the documentation.

what I would like would start with

```
class BooBuilder(): Builder<Boo> { //...
```

I understand that I should start with

```
TypeSpec
  .classBuilder("BooBuilder")
  .addSuperinterface( /* I have no idea what to put here */ )
  // add methods
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass a `ParameterizedTypeName` as a parameter to `addSuperinterface`. To create the `ParameterizedTypeName` you can use `KClass<*>.parameterizedBy` extention function

**Example**

```
import com.squareup.kotlinpoet.ParameterizedTypeName.Companion.parameterizedBy


val booKClass = Boo::class

val booBuilderType = TypeSpec
    .classBuilder("BooBuilder")
    .addSuperinterface(Builder::class.parameterizedBy(booKClass))
    .addFunction(
        FunSpec.builder("build")
            .addModifiers(KModifier.OVERRIDE)
            .addStatement("TODO()")
            .returns(booKClass)
            .build()
    )
    .build()

val kotlinFile = FileSpec.builder("com.example", "BooBuilder")
    .addType(booBuilderType)
    .build()

kotlinFile.writeTo(System.out)
```

**Output**

```
package com.example    

class BooBuilder : Builder<Boo> {
    override fun build(): Boo {
        TODO()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot. A piece of additional information, for anyone reading this in the future. You need to `import com.squareup.kotlinpoet.ParameterizedTypeName.Companion.parameterizedBy`

Comment: Yeah, @Lukasz, it was troublesome to me too, I'll update the answers

Comment: Right, there's a longstanding IDE issue where it won't import extension functions defined in companion objects, it should be fixed in 1.3.20. For now, just add the import manually.